# Python - How to prevent Undo from unloading image data blocks

Tags: python, data-blocks

I am working on an add-on which has a complex user interface and an integrated asset manager (Think blender kit interface). As such I want to load a large number of small thumbnail images into blender on launch, or alternatively when a modal operator is first called. Unfortunately any images from bpy.data.images I load in using app handlers (see below) or using the modal operator are removed by Blender's undo function when the appropriate undo step is removed.

Does anyone know how to prevent Blender from removing images when Undo is called? Currently I'm simply checking to see if Blender has removed the images and reloading them if it has, but this is not exactly efficient.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "ImageLoad",
    "author": "Richard Rose",
    "description": "",
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "location": "",
    "warning": "",
    "category": "Generic"
}

import os
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

def image_load_init_on_activation(dummy):
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_pre.remove(image_load_init_on_activation)
    load_images()


@persistent
def image_load_init_on_load(dummy):
    load_images()


def load_images():
    addon_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    image_path = os.path.join(
        addon_path,
        "assets",
        "test_image.png")

    if os.path.exists(image_path):
        img = bpy.data.images.load(image_path, check_existing=True)
        img.use_fake_user = True  # does nothing


bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_pre.append(image_load_init_on_activation)
bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(image_load_init_on_load)

def register():
    pass

def unregister():
    pass
```